# Can "vote" be used as noun "voting" in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context, american-english

in this HeadLine from NYtimes:

> "A failed Speaker vote for Kevin McCarthy would be a historic event"

is "Vote" working as "voting"?? like:

"A failed Speaker voting for Kevin McCarthy would be a historic event"

so "Speaker voting" would be a voting for electing a Speaker

Comment: Did you check a dictionary "vote: a formal indication of a choice between two or more candidates or courses of action, expressed typically through a ballot or a show of hands."

Comment: @James K, would "a failed Speaker vote" make a Speaker that failed at ballot? does not make sense to me

Comment: That is your misunderstanding...  It is a "speaker vote" that has failed, not a vote by a failed speaker.[

Comment: @James K, to help me understand let me ask: what it takes to a "Speaker vote" to fail? not enough voters?

Comment: That is politics... A speaker vote fails if the majority leader (or some other nominated person) fails to be elected speaker.

Comment: @James, fails by the means of not getting enough votes? or other reason? the logic of how it works help me reasoning about the sentence

Comment: by not getting enough votes. Please, if you have question about the US political system ask on [politics.se]

Comment: @James K, ok. Please check thisout: https://www.usatoday.com/story/news/politics/2023/01/02/house-speaker-vote-explained/10912271002/ you wil find this: "the House was unable to pick a speaker on the first vote." they are using the word "vote" as "voting" right? I mean vote there is not a verb

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141753/discussion-between-james-k-and-berinja-tela).

Comment: @James K, what is really confusing me is the use of the word vote. it make think on the cast of only one ballot and we know votes are casted to elect the Speaker or any other candidate. that is why my mind only reads Speaker voting why do they refer to the process of voting to elect a Speaker as vote? get it?

Answer (score 5):

Your proposed sentence would change the meaning.

In the original sentence, the subject is **vote**, meaning "a formal indication of a choice between two or more candidates or courses of action, expressed typically through a ballot or a show of hands" as James K mentioned in a comment.

So what kind of vote are we talking about?  A **Speaker** vote.  This is kind of American political slang, but what we are talking about is the position of [Speaker of the United States House of Representatives](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speaker_of_the_United_States_House_of_Representatives).  So the vote is on whether Kevin McCarthy becomes Speaker.  A **failed Speaker vote** would mean a vote, on whether McCarthy becomes Speaker, that fails (he does not become Speaker).

Let's look at your version: "**a failed Speaker voting** for Kevin McCarthy would be a historic event."  In this case, the subject phrase is **a failed Speaker voting**, and the noun is **voting**, which means a particular example of the action of casting a vote.  This phrasing makes it sound like "a failed Speaker" is casting a vote, but that doesn't make any sense in this context.  There is no "failed Speaker" we could be referring to.

Comment: so "Speaker vote" in this case is a vote for elect a Speaker right in this case Kevin McCarthy or other. Is that it?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  I think referring to it as a "Speaker vote" is a bit of political journalist slang; we would never say "President vote" when referring to the general election for the presidency.

Comment: @stangdon, i this case a vote means a  referendum right?

Comment: @Berinjatela No, it's an actual vote.  The members of the House of Representatives cast their vote for who will be Speaker.

Comment: @stangdon, if we are talking about  members of the House casting their vote then why we are not using the word "voting" and instead we are using the word "vote" like it is the one vote. "Speaker vote"

Comment: @Berinjatela Because it is one _instance_ of voting. The whole House votes individually, but the process of doing that and counting the votes is a single vote.

Comment: @Austin Hemmelgar, why they consider this whole process a single vote? are there other votes or instances?

Comment: @Berinjatela Because the House is treated as a singular entity in this context since what matters (from a procedural perspective) is the result of everyone voting, not how each individual representative voted. It’s conceptually similar to how you might talk about a corporation as a singular entity when discussing things they produce or services they offer, even though a corporation consists of many people.

Comment: @Austin Hemmelgarn, make perfect sense to me now. thank you. can I ask you the difference between vote and voting or should i open a new post for it?

Comment: @Berinjatela It’s probably better to open a new question for that. The short answer is that ‘voting’ is a generic noun while ‘vote’ is not, but explaining that properly and why that matters in this case is a bit long for comments, and it’s a useful discussion in general.

Answer (score 1):

"A failed Speaker voting for Kevin McCarthy would be a historic event" is incorrect. Voting can only be used as a noun when referring to a general activity. For example, "Voting is important to maintain a functional democracy.". I'm not referring to your vote or my vote; I'm referring to the voting process in general.

Comment: then what would be a "falied Speaker vote"?

Comment: a failed Speaker vote would be a yes or no answer from a Speaker that didn't achieve its desired purpose. Failed Speaker voting would refer to all such answers from all Speakers, not just McCarthy.

Answer (score 0):

The original sentence:

> A failed Speaker vote for Kevin McCarthy would be a historic event.

Is grammatically valid, and is fully natural. A fluent speaker would understand and might well say or write this sentence.

Your proposed alternative:

> "A failed Speaker voting for Kevin McCarthy would be a historic event"

is not valid. The word "voting" cannot be used in that way. "Voting" describes th process of casting votes, but is not used for the event at which they are cast. See the [Cambridge Dictionary defination](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/voting)

The word  "vote" can be used for an individual person's selection. But it can also be used for an event at which votes are cast. In this sense, it is a near synonym of "election. See:

- [Merriam-webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vote) Entry 2 sense 4a

> the act or process of voting

Entry 2, sense 2:

> the collective opinion or verdict of a body of persons expressed by voting : the result of a vote

- [Britannica](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/vote) Sense 2:

> to make a decision about (someone or something) by voting

- [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/vote) Sense B2

> a way of making a decision by asking a group of people to vote:

In this sense "a speaker vote" is a short form for "a vote or speaker" or "an election to choose a speaker".

A "failed speaker vote" is when a person is formally proposed as speaker (of the House) but is not approved by a sufficient majority of those voting. This is an example of headlineese, a shortens form used particularly  in news headlines to summarize, in a catchy way, the fuller story.

This is not a "referendum" that is what happens when a proposal is **refereed** to then people at large, form them to approve or disapprove it by voting on it. This is a vote of the members of the US House of Representatives, one of th4e two sections of the US Congress.